# LS-00201: identifier 'SYB12ALLPLATFORM.STAGECAPTURE' error while migrating from oracle to sybase

Tags: oracle, sybase-ase15

I am trying to migrate from oracle to sybase ase 15.7 with oracle sql developer, and after minutes of migration loading appearing, I got this error:

```
LS-00201: identifier 'SYB12ALLPLATFORM.STAGECAPTURE' must be declared
```

Do you have any idea what is the reason of this? The below is the full error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<log>
<record>
  <date>2017-08-28T13:51:56</date>
  <logger>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.MigrationLogResourceBundle</logger>
  <level>SEVERE</level>
  <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.logging.MigrationLogUtil</class>
  <message>Capture
Enterprise Capture
Capture failed.  Refer to MIGRLOG table in the repository for details</message>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask.doOnlineEnterpriseCapture(FullMigrateTask.java:758)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask.doCapture(FullMigrateTask.java:601)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask.doMaskBasedActions(FullMigrateTask.java:400)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask.doWork(FullMigrateTask.java:314)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask.doWork(FullMigrateTask.java:147)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:193)</param>
  <param>java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:554)</param>
  <param>java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)</param>
  <param>java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)</param>
  <param>java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)</param>
  <param>java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)</param>
  <param>java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)</param>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.logging.LogInfo@6dbe5dcc</param>
  <exception>
    <message>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask$FullMigrateTaskException: Capture
Enterprise Capture
Capture failed.  Refer to MIGRLOG table in the repository for details</message>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
      <line>758</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
      <line>601</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
      <line>400</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
      <line>314</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
      <line>147</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask</class>
      <line>193</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.util.concurrent.FutureTask</class>
      <line>262</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask</class>
      <line>554</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter</class>
      <line>471</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.util.concurrent.FutureTask</class>
      <line>262</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor</class>
      <line>1145</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker</class>
      <line>615</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>java.lang.Thread</class>
      <line>744</line>
    </frame>
  </exception>

</record>
<record>
  <date>2017-08-28T13:51:56</date>
  <logger>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.MigrationLogResourceBundle</logger>
  <level>WARNING</level>
  <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.ui.FullMigrateTask</class>
  <message>Error:ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYB12ALLPLATFORM.STAGECAPTURE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
: FAILED : Database Migration : FAILED</message>
  <param>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.logging.LogInfo@4d011574</param>

</record>
```

Comment: title says 'oracle to sybase' while your first sentence says 'sybase to oracle' ... which is it? (I'm guessing it's `sybase to oracle` as I can't see Oracle providing any tools to migrate from Oracle) also, which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage) are you using?

Comment: check my edit @markp

Comment: I don't work with oracle sql developer so fwiw ... this item - [STAGECAPTURE error](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3533176) - mentions a) creating a migration repository in Oracle and b) an issue with permissions

Comment: @markp they didnt mention that a repository .. i eill do that as for the permision i did grant some .. i eil check tomrow . thank you